# JSON file from URL - Front End Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am required to pull a data from a [URL](https://api.mcmakler.de/v1/advertisements)

So that I can display the first ten of the data in HTML. I am having problem because I don't really understand the process.

I managed to pull the data using this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://crossorigin.me/https://api.mcmakler.de/v1/advertisements',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: displayAll
    });

function displayAll(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

How do I use the data and display it using HTML?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a JS framework like Angular, React, or Vue to bind the json to html elements/templates.

I suggest going to the Vue website and walking through the tutorials.

Comment: just throw the object into `JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)` and throw the result into a `<pre>` block. voila. not even worth writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That ajax call should return an object that has a `.data` attribute, which contains an array of objects with the data you want to display. You just loop over the array and then use dot notation to access the properties you want to display. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://crossorigin.me/https://api.mcmakler.de/v1/advertisements',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "json",
  success: displayAll
});

function displayAll(data) {
  let html = '';
  // the object that is returned as "data" contains a property called
  // "data" that contains the collection of objects
  data.data.forEach(function (item) {
    // Add a div containing information on this item to the HTML we will output
    html += `<div id="item_${item._id.$id}>
      <span class="title">${item.title}</span>
      <span class="rent">Rental price: ${item.advertisementPrice.baseRent}</span>
      <span class="buy">Sell price: ${item.advertisementPrice.sellPrice}</span>`;
  });

  // #target is the element on the page you want to put the information in
  $('#target').html(html);
}
```

Please note that at the time of writing this answer, https://crossorigin.me/ appears to have a an invalid HTTPS certificate and might not be reachable, thus causing an error instead of returning data.